# Setting max and min height for hero div

Tags: html, css

So, I'm creating a landing page for a client and they want a full-screen hero div with a playing video in the background. The conventional way to do this is for it to be done through:

```css
div.hero {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

However, I'm being awkward and I need the position to be declared as `relative`. I also want to limit the height so that you can't shrink the div below `640px`, and can't stretch it more than `800px`.

Here's my code:

```css
div.hero {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 800px;
    min-height: 640px;
    display: block;
}
```

The issue occurs that the box does not become `100%` height, and instead it scales to `640px`.

How could I fix this?

Comment: guess what you need is `fixed` *positioning* and not `absolute` or `relative`?

Comment: Please can you create a [mcve] as we don't know what your relative div is going to take 100% height or width of, or where it sits within your code.  My guess though, your div is sitting in an element whose height is not more than 640px;

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. You want to have it full-screen and yet you want it to be no more than 800px tall.

Comment: As explained, this div is to display hero content on a webpage and therefore is a child of the document itself, not another div. If a user has a screen of 640px in height, the hero div will shrink to that size. If the user has a screen of 800px in height, the hero div will grow to that size (and of course anything between these two boundaries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 100vh instead of 100% in height and it will work.

```css
div.hero {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 800px;
    min-height: 640px;
    display: block;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```css
    html, body {height:100%; margin:0; }

    div.hero {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 800px;
        min-height: 640px;
        display: block; 
        background:blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Comment: note that this has better browser support, e.g: IE8 does not support `vh`, `vw` units

Comment: also, consider removing `max-height`